# Как с помощью IndexOf найти все вхождения элемента в массив?

Tags: c#, массивы, indexof

Реализую программу для нахождения первого вхождения элемента в массив, но не могу понять, как находить все вхождения.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of elements in array:");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] array = new int[n];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                array[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the value you are looking for:");
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int index = Array.IndexOf(array, m);
            if (index == -1)
               Console.WriteLine("There is no desired number.");
            else
               Console.Write("The first time value on position [{0}] ", index);



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Требуется посчитать количество вхождений или вывести индексы всех вхождений?

Comment: Наложить фильтр и вывести индексы отфильтрованных элементов.

Comment: Посмотрите все перегрузки метода: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof

Comment: @alladuh, индексы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = -1;
do
{
    index = Array.IndexOf(array, m, index + 1);
    if(index != -1)
        Console.WriteLine(index);
}
while(index != -1);
```

Вероятно, так должно сработать. Третий параметр в `IndexOf` задаёт позицию, с которой необходимо начинать искать. То есть здесь мы каждую итерацию начинаем искать не сначала, а с того места, где остановились в прошлый раз. Этот код выведет индексы всех вхождений.

Comment: Один нюнс: в конце также выведится -1

Comment: @alladuh Да, спасибо, поправлю

Comment: это рабочий вариант, но надо иметь ввиду, что он будет очень медленным. Если, например, у нас будет миллион элементов, все равны 1, и мы будем искать 1, то это будет миллион вызовов `Array.IndexOf`, то есть вместо линейного времени, мы получим квадратичное.

Comment: хотя я, возможно, не прав про квадратичное время, зависит от реазизации IndexOf, вожможно и линейное.

Comment: @tym32167, такое же линейное время и будет. Мы же начинаем отсчет с того места, где остановились в прошлый раз

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, я потому и отписал, просто некогда пока проверять код, но я вам на слово поверю, да и оно логично :)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ однострочник

```
var arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2,3, 4, 5};
var target = 3;

var indexes = arr.Select((a,i)=>(a,i)).Where(x=>x.a == target).Select(x=>x.i).ToArray();

foreach(var index in indexes) Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Вывод

```
2
6
11
```

Comment: Красиво)
Такой вопрос: почему в `a` и в `i` кладутся число и его индекс?

Comment: @alladuh ну это параметр одной из перегрузок для [Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) - `A transform function to apply to each source element; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.`

Comment: это действительно круто, спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @alladuh пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я сейчас приведу не самый универсальный способ. Думаю, что можно проще сделать через LINQ.

Создаём пустой массив для хранения индексов вхождения:

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>();
```

Проходим по исходному массиву и проверяем на совпадение

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    if(array[i] == m)
       arr.Add(i);
```

Comment: не проще ли тогда `List<int>` использовать?

Comment: Да, вы правы! Сейчас подправлю